# Running Selenium from eclipse + browser says file not found for base url

Tags: selenium, file-not-found

I am trying to run Selenium from eclipse. 
This is the code that I am executing -

```
Selenium selenium = 
new DefaultSelenium("localhost",4444,"*iexplore","http://www.google.com");

selenium.start();
```

The browser opens up with the baseurl but it displays a 404 error saying 'file not found' (be it any website I specify). Like for example in this case, I get the message shown in the image -

http://i51.tinypic.com/2cpxoio.jpg

Can anyone please help me out this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proceed the statements above with -

```
selenium.open("/");
selenium.windowFocus();
```

Comment: Hey that helped me with http sites. Thanks. But in case of https sites, I am still getting the same issue.